# Jbutton to redirect to 2FA url authenticate and come back to application with new page

Tags: java, 12factor

when the username and passwords is correct the Jbutton takes the user to the OKTA verify webpage the user authenticates and is redirected to the java application but the page after the login

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: no worries all good the question has been resolved thanks